# PHP: compare arrays by values return keys of different

Tags: php, arrays, compare

Probably a duplicate...

```
Array1 = ['a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3];
Array1 = ['a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>'anaconda'];
$keys = ISTHEREAFUCNTION(array1, array2);

echo ($keys);

// c
```

Is there a function that compares arrays by value and return keys of array1 values different from values of array2?

I can do it just iterating over both arrays, but maybe there is a more elegant solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Google: php array difference. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 1):

Using [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

```
$ cat test.php
<?php

$arr1 = ['a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3];
$arr2 = ['a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>'anaconda'];
print_r(array_keys(array_diff($arr1,$arr2)));

?>

$ php test.php
Array
(
    [0] => c
)
```

Comment: thank you! feel stupid now) I thought that array_diff returns only diff.values, and re-writes the keys:)

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_keys](http://php.net/array_keys) and [array_diff_assoc](http://php.net/array_diff_assoc)

```
array_keys(array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2));
```